# SELECT emails and on number of emails returned insert new row another table PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, for-loop, while-loop

It only returns one email while there are multiple in the database. I want to select all emails and copy them to the new table.

```
$qry5 = $con->prepare("SELECT email from ssrod.emails where WebformId = ? AND Agency_Id = ?");
        $qry5->bind_param("ss", $WebformIdToCopy, $_SESSION['AgencyId']);
        $qry5->execute();
        $qry5->store_result();
        $qry5->bind_result($copiedEmail);
        $qry5->fetch();
        $numberOfEmail = $qry3->num_rows;
        $counter = 0;
        if ($qry5->num_rows > 0) {
            for($i = 0; $i<$numberOfEmail; $i++) {
                $qry6 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO ssrod.emails (WebformId, Agency_Id, LOBId, email ) values (?,?,?,?)");
                $qry6->bind_param("ssss", $newAddedWebformId , $_SESSION['AgencyId'], $LOBId, $copiedEmail);
                $qry6->execute();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just use while instead of for

Comment: I used while before adding the for loop the result is the same

Comment: You need to loop through the fetch() maybe the example here can help you: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: Thank you @Baracuda078. I clicked and followed the steps to the while loop and I used the fetch twice in my while loop code (not the one we have above) but the same as Adyson commented...

Comment: I can't make sense of the title of this Question.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a loop!

```
INSERT INTO ssrod.emails (WebformId, Agency_Id, LOBId, email ) 
    SELECT ?, ?, ?, email 
    FROM ssrod.emails 
    WHERE WebformId = ? AND Agency_Id = ?;
```

You seem to understand parameters.  Next, *always* use them!

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the number of rows actually returned, you'll only ever see one value for `$copiedEmail` because you only `fetch()` once - fetch only returns one row at a time.

Remove `$qry5->fetch();` and then replace `for($i = 0; $i<$numberOfEmail; $i++) {` with `while ($qry5->fetch()) {` and you should get better results. The `if ($qry5->num_rows > 0) { ... }` wrapper should also be redundant - it already won't enter the loop if there are no rows returned.

Complete example:

```
$qry5 = $con->prepare("SELECT email from ssrod.emails where WebformId = ? AND Agency_Id = ?");
$qry5->bind_param("ss", $WebformIdToCopy, $_SESSION['AgencyId']);
$qry5->execute();
$qry5->bind_result($copiedEmail);

while ($qry5->fetch()) {
  $qry6 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO ssrod.emails (WebformId, Agency_Id, LOBId, email ) values (?,?,?,?)");
  $qry6->bind_param("ssss", $newAddedWebformId , $_SESSION['AgencyId'], $LOBId, $copiedEmail);
  $qry6->execute();
}
```

---

N.B. The above notes explain the technical reason for your problem. However, as [this answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63523583/5947043), it isn't actually necessary to use 2 separate queries at all, so most of your code is really not required, and this issue need not have arisen at all to begin with.

Comment: Thanks the problem was the fetched on line 5. and I removed it and used your code it worked. Thanks